# Centos+Apache+Phusion+REE=FAIL

Tags: apache-2.2, centos5, ruby, selinux, phusion-passenger

I have been trying to get Phusion Passenger running on 5.6 for the last couple of days with no luck. Initially, I started with Ruby 1.9.2 under RVM since the default Ruby on RHEL-based distros is quite old. I got everything installed OK but ran into some issues. Thinking it was RVM, I completely removed it along with the default Ruby and installed Ruby Enterprise Ed. 1.8.7.2011-03 into `/usr`. I am still having the same issues.

When I try to Passenger with the default setup instructions provided by the installer, I got an error message saying `cannot find phusion_passenger/analytics_logger`. I found very little info about this from Google but from what I can surmise it is a permissions error.
 Initially, I tried setting an ACL allowing user access for the apache user to the passenger root directory. Failing that, I tried chmod-ing the passenger root to 777. Next I tried changing the context of the passenger root and its parent directory to `httpd_sys_content_t` as per section 6.3.5 of the user guide. Last, I tried setting SELinux to permissive. Nothing worked.

After reading through the user guide, I tried the following settings which resulted in a 500 ISE:

```
PassengerUserSwitching off
PassengerUser apache
PassengerGroup apache
```

Here is my `passenger.conf` file minus the above (from `/etc/httpd/conf.d`):

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.7/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.7
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
....
PassengerLogLevel 3
```

This is the log output from the 500 error:

```
[ pid=17939 thr=1094539584 file=ext/common/ApplicationPool/Pool.h:939 time=2011-04-30 13:12:17.351 ]: Spawning a process for /var/www/html because there are none for this app group
[ pid=17939 thr=1094539584 file=ext/common/ApplicationPool/../SpawnManager.h:291 time=2011-04-30 13:12:17.352 ]: Spawning a new application process for /var/www/html...
[ pid=17939 thr=1094539584 file=ext/common/ApplicationPool/../SpawnManager.h:427 time=2011-04-30 13:12:17.352 ]: Spawn server died. Attempting to restart it...
[ pid=17939 thr=1094539584 file=ext/common/ApplicationPool/../SpawnManager.h:430 time=2011-04-30 13:12:17.357 ]: Restart seems to be successful.
[ pid=17939 thr=1094539584 file=ext/common/ApplicationPool/../SpawnManager.h:291 time=2011-04-30 13:12:17.359 ]: Spawning a new application process for /var/www/html...
/usr/bin/ruby: error while loading shared libraries: libtcmalloc_minimal.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[ pid=17939 thr=1094539584 file=ext/common/ApplicationPool/Server.h:297 time=2011-04-30 13:12:17.365 ]: Client 9: SpawnException occured (no error page)
[ pid=17951 thr=47853881642864 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:865 time=2011-04-30 13:12:17.366 ]: Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application '/var/www/html': Could not read from the spawn server: Connection reset by peer (104)
  Backtrace:
     in 'virtual Passenger::SessionPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool::Client::get(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (Client.h:750)
     in 'Passenger::SessionPtr Hooks::getSession(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (Hooks.cpp:297)
     in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:566)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when you say you removed the default Ruby, I hope you aren't meaning the one that ships with CentOS. In my experience, it's best to just leave that one alone, and let yum manage it. I install my Ruby/REE versions into /opt/ruby, but they could go in /usr/local, or wherever you wanted.

As far as configuring SELinux, I personally disable it, but permissive shouldn't be any different than that. From a base install, I just add the typical packages needed for compiling packages, and do a full upgrade:

```
# yum -y install gcc make gcc-c++ cpp automake patch zlib-devel && yum -y upgrade
```

Then I install REE 1.8.7-2011.03:

```
# ./installer --dont-install-useful-gems --no-dev-docs --auto /opt/ruby/enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03
```

Make sure Apache (httpd) is installed, and then install the passenger gem, and the corresponding Apache module:

```
# /opt/ruby/enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/bin/gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri --version '= 3.0.7' passenger
# /opt/ruby/enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module -a
```

Add what it tells you, to Apache's httpd.conf. I use the following:

```
SetEnv MY_RUBY_HOME "/opt/ruby/enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03"
SetEnv GEM_HOME "/opt/ruby/enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"
SetEnv GEM_PATH "/opt/ruby/enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"
LoadModule passenger_module /opt/ruby/enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.7/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /opt/ruby/enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.7
PassengerRuby /opt/ruby/enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/bin/ruby
```

Then, I deploy a simple Rails application to /home/httpd/app, and add a VirtualHost similar to the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /home/httpd/app/public
  RackBaseURI /
  RailsEnv production
  PassengerSpawnMethod smart
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure all the gems that your application will require are installed, including "rails".

Throughout the setup, you *shouldn't* have to anything too special with file permissions, other than you will have to keep in mind that your app will run as the user/group of the owner of the Rails app root. This user will have to have at least r-x permissions on all of the /opt/ruby stuff.

I honestly don't know why you are getting the `/usr/bin/ruby: error while loading shared libraries: libtcmalloc_minimal.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` error, but if you follow the above directions, and make sure not to bother with your system Ruby, you shouldn't have any problems.

I'm sorry that I didn't really answer your question, but I'm hoping my tried and trusted process will work equally as well for you as it does for myself!

Comment: Thanks walkeran. Yes I did completely remove the Ruby that came with CentOS. I figured it was safe to since nothing was actually using it and I was having issues with RVM. I'll try to integrate your settings with mine when I get home from work and see what happens. Thanks again!

Comment: @blu Funny story.. I'm not sure what planet on when I was writing that answer, but the minor "freak out" I had about messing with the Ruby from CentOS repositories was a bit unwarranted. For some reason, I was confusing Ruby with Python, and I got all concerned that yum and some other packages might just quit working...that said, I would still (personally) install it to /opt or /usr/local to avoid confusion. I'm looking forward to see how these steps work out for you, so keep us in the loop!

Comment: It's OK. If you go anywhere near Python on CentOS it will freak out. I learned that lesson while trying to strip down my Git server.

Comment: I tried your settings and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Nevermind; I went back to the original setup (removed PassengerUser* lines) in combination with your settings and it works now! Thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it ended up working out for you in the end!